# Detect, whether an exception occured when using "ValidatesOnExceptions"

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Imagine a WPF project with an MVVM approach. So, there is a view and a view model.

In the view model I have a property, that might throw an exception in the setter.

```
Public Property DateValue As Nullable(Of Date)
    Get
        Return _dateValue
    End Get
    Set(value As Nullable(Of Date))
        If value.HasValue Then
            If value.Value < Date.Today Then
                Throw New Exception("Error Message")
            End If
        End If

        _dateValue = value
        'skipped NotifyPropertyChanged in this example for the sake of simplicity
    End Set
End Property
```

In the view there is a control bound to this property. And since I like to see my exceptions I switched on `ValidatesOnExceptions` in the binding and add an `ErrorTemplate`.

```
...
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding DateValue, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"
            SelectedDateFormat="Short"
            Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}" />
...
```

Since you can't reset the value of a `DatePicker` once you picked one (at least I don't know how to do that) I added a small reset button right next to the `DatePicker` which is bound to a command which sets the property `DateValue` of the view model to `Nothing`. And since I don't want to see this button all the time I bound its `Visibility` to `DateValue.HasValue`, so this button only shows, when there's a value to reset.

So far, so good.

But now I have a problem when I pick an invalid date in the `DatePicker` (one that throws an exception in the properties' setter).

My reset button doesn't show up, since there's no value in the bound property, and I can't reset the `DatePicker` any other way (at least not that I know of). I'd first have to pick a proper date before I can reset the whole thing.

So, is there any way to determine, whether my property setter threw an exception. There must be a way, since this very error is shown to the user.

Or do I have to manually remember, that I threw an exception in another variable, to be able to access this information when needed?

And how do I "clear" the `DatePicker`. Since there's no value in the property, setting the property to `Nothing` will not change anything in the view. How would I get rid of the error?

Answer (score 0):

```
Class ViewModel
    Inherits INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private selectedDate As DateTime

    Public Property SelectedDate As DateTime
        Get
            Return Me.selectedDate
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As DateTime)

            If value < DateTime.Today Then
                Throw New ArgumentException("Date can't be in the past.")
            End If

            Me.selectedDate = value
            OnPropertyChanged()
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property ResetDateCommand As ICommand
        Get
            Return New RelayCommand(AddressOf ExecuteResetDate)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        Me.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today
    End Sub

    Public Sub ExecuteResetDate(ByVal commandParameter As Object)
        Return CSharpImpl.__Assign(Me.SelectedDate, DateTime.Today)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.Resources>
  
  <StackPanel x:Name="RootPanel" viewModels:Item.IsMarkedAsRead="True">
    <Button Content="Reset Date"
            Visibility="{Binding ElementName=DatePicker, Path=(Validation.HasError), Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
            Command="{Binding ResetDateCommand}" />
    <DatePicker x:Name="DatePicker" 
                SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"
                SelectedDateFormat="Short" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

### Remarks

It's best practice in UI design that you always prevent wrong input. If possible you shouldn't allow invalid input e.g. by disabling buttons, hiding invalid options, limiting ranges etc.
Don't allow the user to select invalid options. This leads to a frustrating user experience. One way to prevent wrong input is to use specialized controls. Instead of forcing the user to type a date you offer a `DatePicker`. This eliminates typos. But it can also eliminate wrong selections by providing only valid dates.

If you want to disallow selecting dates of the past you can narrow down the selectable range:

```
<!-- Only show dates from today -->
<DatePicker DisplayDateStart="{x:Static system:DateTime.Today}" />
```

If you have additional illegal dates e.g. holidays you can define a collection of those dates by setting the `DatePicker.BlackoutDates` property:

**DatePickerHelper.cs**

```
Class DatePickerHelper
    Inherits DependencyObject

    Public Shared ReadOnly BlackedDaysProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BlackedDays", GetType(IEnumerable(Of CalendarDateRange)), GetType(DatePickerHelper), New PropertyMetadata(Nothing, AddressOf DatePickerHelper.OnBlackDatesChanged))

    Public Shared Sub SetBlackedDays(ByVal attachingElement As DependencyObject, ByVal value As IEnumerable(Of CalendarDateRange))
        Return attachingElement.SetValue(DatePickerHelper.BlackedDaysProperty, value)
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function GetBlackedDays(ByVal attachingElement As DependencyObject) As IEnumerable(Of CalendarDateRange)
        Return CType(attachingElement.GetValue(DatePickerHelper.BlackedDaysProperty), IEnumerable(Of CalendarDateRange))
    End Function

    Private Shared ReadOnly Property DatePickerTable As Dictionary(Of INotifyCollectionChanged, DatePicker)

    Private Shared Sub New()
        DatePickerHelper.DatePickerTable = New Dictionary(Of INotifyCollectionChanged, DatePicker)()
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub OnBlackDatesChanged(ByVal d As DependencyObject, ByVal e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        Dim attachedDatePicker = TryCast(d, DatePicker)
        Dim oldObservableCollection As INotifyCollectionChanged = Nothing

        If CSharpImpl.__Assign(oldObservableCollection, TryCast(e.OldValue, INotifyCollectionChanged)) IsNot Nothing Then
            oldObservableCollection.CollectionChanged -= AddressOf UpdateDatePickerBlockedDates
            DatePickerHelper.DatePickerTable.Remove(oldObservableCollection)
        End If

        Dim newObservableCollection As INotifyCollectionChanged = Nothing

        If CSharpImpl.__Assign(newObservableCollection, TryCast(e.NewValue, INotifyCollectionChanged)) IsNot Nothing Then
            newObservableCollection.CollectionChanged += AddressOf UpdateDatePickerBlockedDates
            DatePickerHelper.DatePickerTable.Add(newObservableCollection, attachedDatePicker)
        End If

        attachedDatePicker.BlackoutDates.AddRange(TryCast(e.NewValue, IEnumerable(Of CalendarDateRange)))
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub UpdateDatePickerBlockedDates(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)
        Dim attachedDatePicker As DatePicker = Nothing

        If Not DatePickerHelper.DatePickerTable.TryGetValue(TryCast(sender, INotifyCollectionChanged), attachedDatePicker) Then
            Return
        End If

        Select Case e.Action
            Case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add
                attachedDatePicker.BlackoutDates.AddRange(e.NewItems.OfType(Of CalendarDateRange)())
            Case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace
                e.OldItems.OfType(Of CalendarDateRange)().ToList().ForEach(Function(removedItem) attachedDatePicker.BlackoutDates.Remove(removedItem))
            Case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move
            Case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset
                attachedDatePicker.BlackoutDates.Clear()
            Case Else
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
Class ViewModel
    Public Property BlockedDates As ObservableCollection(Of CalendarDateRange)

    // Block Christmas holidays and all days in the past
    Public Sub New()
        Return CSharpImpl.__Assign(Me.BlockedDates, New ObservableCollection(Of CalendarDateRange) From {
            New CalendarDateRange(New DateTime(2020, 12, 24), New DateTime(2020, 12, 26)),
            New CalendarDateRange(DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.Today.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(1)))
        })
    End Sub
End Class
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<!-- Only show dates from today -->
<DatePicker DatePickerHelper.BlackedDays="{Binding BlockedDates}" />
```

Comment: Thank you. I go with the `DisplayDateStart` and the `DisplayDateEnd`, that's good enough for me. Doesn't solve all possible restrictions though. Let's just say "Pick any date, but it has to be a leap year". The `BlackedDays` collection would get pretty big.

Comment: Just tested it, the `DatePicker` allows the user to enter a date. When setting `DisplayDateStart` and `DisplayDateEnd` and entering a date outside of these bounds, I'm in the same position again. The `DatePicker` shows an error but doesn't show the reset button, since there's no value to reset in the bound property.

Comment: You are not able to prevent _every_ invalid input. There is a point where you have to validate user input. But generally a good UI doesn't give the user the chance to input invalid data or at least does everything possible to prevent this. Error messages are always annoying and interrupting the work flow. I have already addressed the error handling by showing the reset button in the first part of my answer. When pressing the button the date is set to today. Please try it and let me know if you have issues.

Comment: Oh, I missed the `Visibility` binding of the button to `Validation.HasErrors`. I'll experiment with that. Thank you.